# Searching in a linked list based on frequency of search

Tags: linked-list

Suppose there is an unsorted linked list in the memory. Suggest a suitable search procedure in which
the frequently searched elements will be found with lesser number of comparisons. (You may modify
the data structure if you wish.)

How to do this?

Comment: What about LRU algorithm?  seen this post: https://krishankantsinghal.medium.com/my-first-blog-on-medium-583159139237

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way to achieve this is

- search for the required element in the unsorted linked list (linear search)
- if found, delete that node from there and make it as head node (deletion and insertion operation)
- so next time lesser comparisons will be needed to find that node.
- all the elements which are already searched will be present close to head and thus it's retrieval will be efficient.

Comment: Got it. This method is very much similar to the implementation of the Least recently used algorithm.